# Control TextBox in c# that only admits 8 numbers and only one last letter

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make in c# a textbox that only admits 8 first numbers and one last letter like DNI in Spain. Here is my code:

```
private void textBox5_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) 
        {
            int contador = 0;

            do
            {
                e.Handled = !(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back); //8 numeros

                contador++;

            } while (contador < 8);

            if (contador == 8) // Si se han escrito 8 numeros hago que se escriba la ultima letra
            {
                e.Handled = false;

                textBox5.MaxLength = 9;

                if(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }           
            }
        }
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 4):

There is better control to achieve your goal than standard `TextBox`. Take a look at `MaskedTextBox` that is available with standard `winforms` controls. All you need to do is to set `Mask` property. In your case it will be:

```
maskedTextBox1.Mask = "00000000L";
```

`0 -    Digit, required. This element will accept any single digit between 0 and 9.`

`L -    Letter, required. Restricts input to the ASCII letters a-z and A-Z. This mask element is equivalent to [a-zA-Z] in regular expressions.`

For more information check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask?view=net-5.0) link.